# TYPO3 Translation and Media Files

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-8.7.x

When you translated a page in TYPO3 (TYPO3 8 LTS) you got those values from the origin language on each field. That works fine for everything but images. 
is there a way, that if you add an image in the origin language the image will also be added in the translations?

Answer (score 0):

```
'behaviour' => [
    'allowLanguageSynchronization' => true,
],
```

In your TCA config of the inline element. Just tried that, works also for tt_content image and assets. However I'm not sure from the top of my head if you can set / unset that on a tt_content element type basis (only for some CE's via columsOverrides or not).

For more details on this setting, see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ColumnsConfig/Type/Inline.html#allowlanguagesynchronization - this setting is available for various types.